# Loop Through JSON List How and What is Problem with script?

Tags: json

Following is the Script i am working that will indicate the Feature Detection for Firefox i created a Json list i want to call each to check in the script to see wehther its undefined or not but its not working can someone help me i am too much exhausted....!!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var JsonList = 
{
    "CheckSet": [
        {
            "property": "azimuth",
            "result": 0 
        },
        {
            "property": "cue",
            "result": 0 
        } 
    ] 
};


function Check()
{
    //alert('working');
    var looptrav;
    var looplist = JsonList;
    var indicator = 0;

    for(looptrav = 0; looptrav < looplist.CheckSet.length; looptrav++)
    {
        if(typeof(looplist.CheckSet[looptrav].property) != "undefined") 
        {
            looplist.CheckSet[looptrav].result = 1;
            indicator = 1;
            document.write ("Result: "+looplist.CheckSet[looptrav].result);
        }
}

Check();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your call to the `Check()`-function?

Comment: I edited the code suppose if we do that like i edited as JsonList is available to all functions then whats the problem ?? Please Help me out because i am too much tired of it...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonList` (or `looplist`) is an `Object`, not an `Array`, so it doesn't have a `length` property. It however does have a property `CheckSet` which you correctly access further on (with one exception)  and which is an `Array`.

So you need to change

```
for(looptrav = 0; looptrav < looplist.length; looptrav++)
```

to

```
for(looptrav = 0; looptrav < looplist.CheckSet.length; looptrav++)
```

and change

```
looplist[looptrav].result = 1;
```

to

```
looplist.CheckSet[looptrav].result = 1;
```

---

EDIT: You are missing a closing `}` and it's probably not a good idea to `document.write` inside `<head>`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qjuVk/

Comment: Check the Code i made Changes a bit and your logic also but still not working i posted whole code if it will be done i will be free from like hell :-S!!

Comment: Lots of Thanks for your Help Shit i miss the Bracket :( thats why its bad to use a normal Editor :(...!

Still Lots of Thanks :)...You saved a life :D!!